# If SSD content is changed due to this kind of error, should you get new SSD?

Tags: ssd, ext4, hard-drive-failure

This came up when I booted. When I did the manual `fsck` it told that it changed the content of the drive. Is there a way to know which file(s) is affected?

The system is running Ubuntu 20.04 and this is an SSD I installed myself and have used it some years.

[image: screenshot]

Here is part of the output of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   000   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3588
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3007
148 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4
149 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
167 Write_Protect_Mode      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
168 SATA_Phy_Error_Count    0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Bad_Block_Rate          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       11
170 Bad_Blk_Ct_Erl/Lat      0x0000   100   100   010    Old_age   Offline      -       0/8
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 MaxAvgErase_Ct          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       74 (Average 31)
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Unsafe_Shutdown_Count   0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1599
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   070   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 19/36)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
199 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
218 CRC_Error_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0000   004   004   000    Old_age   Offline      -       96
233 Flash_Writes_GiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5119
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3115
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2161
244 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       31
245 Max_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       74
246 Total_Erase_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       242464

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Comment: [Check the health of your disk using `smartctl`](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-an-hard-drive-health-from-the-command-line-using-smartctl). Copy the "SMART Attributes" section of the report to your post for us to analyze and answer the question.

Comment: When `fsck` made changes, it says that. This is _entirely_ unrelated to where the corruption came from. The source of the corruption could be anything, including a software bug! Try to think of the last time the PC shut down—was it a proper shutdown? Or did the power fail or the battery run out? Or did the operating system crash?

Comment: @DanielB Sometimes I have made unclean shutdowns when OS has freezed for some reason, but I think I shutted down normally before this.

Comment: The drive shows 2 reallocated sectors, but all the other parameters look OK. But the "Unsafe shutdown count" is 1599, which is quite high. The SSD of my main machine shows only 45 unsafe shutdowns after 6 years, and the HDD in the same machine 204 after 11 years.

Comment: @PierU yes I agree that the unsafe shutdown count is high. It might equal the overall shutdown count with that SSD. Currently it is 1605. I have shut down normally recently, so this is very odd.

Comment: Indeed there's something strange here, if the "unsafe shutdown" count continues growing while you are shutting down normally... For some reason the Ubuntu or the motherboard is powering down the drive too early?

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error is a filesystem inconsistency. The underlying reason can be a drive-level error, but this is not the most common one.

A typical reason can be a sudden shutdown because of a power failure (but there are other possible reasons).

So I would'nt worry about the drive... That said it's always good to monitor the SMART status from time to time.